# Is it possible to turn a SqlDbType to a string representation of the default value of the corresponding C# type?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, t-sql

Suppose I have a C# variable of type `SqlDbType` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx) like `BigInt`. The corresponding .NET FrameWork type is `Int64` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx). So the value I want is `default(Int64).ToString()`.

Is there any way to do this dynamically (i.e. not using a wall of `switch` statements)?

Comment: If you *have a variable*, is the value you want not `that_variable.ToString()`?

Comment: Getting the default value of any type is easy - you're doing that in your question. So your question isn't really what you're asking. You're asking if there's a built-in function to convert a `SqlDbType` to a framework type. There's not.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no, you've got to do the conversion manually. There's a full list SQL Server Data Type Mappings [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx).

The easiest way I can think of is to create a couple of helper classes to take care of the conversion. SqlExtension class contains the ToType method, converting a SqlDbType to Type.

```
public static class SqlExtensions
{
    private static readonly IDictionary<SqlDbType, Type> TypeMap = new Dictionary<SqlDbType, Type>
        {
            { SqlDbType.TinyInt, typeof(byte) },
            { SqlDbType.SmallInt, typeof(short) },
            { SqlDbType.Int, typeof(int)},
            { SqlDbType.BigInt,typeof(long) },
            { SqlDbType.Image, typeof(byte[])},
            { SqlDbType.Bit, typeof(bool)},
            { SqlDbType.DateTime, typeof(DateTime)},
            { SqlDbType.DateTime2, typeof(DateTime)},
            { SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset, typeof(DateTimeOffset)},
            { SqlDbType.NVarChar,typeof(string) },
            { SqlDbType.VarChar, typeof(string)},
            { SqlDbType.Text, typeof(string)},
            { SqlDbType.NText, typeof(string)},
            { SqlDbType.Char, typeof(char)},
            { SqlDbType.NChar, typeof(char)},
            { SqlDbType.Money, typeof(decimal)},
            { SqlDbType.Real, typeof(float)},
            { SqlDbType.Float, typeof(double)},
            { SqlDbType.Time, typeof(TimeSpan)}
            // add the rest here
        };

    public static Type ToType(this SqlDbType type)
    {
        if (TypeMap.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            return TypeMap[type];
        }

        throw new ArgumentException($"{type} is not a supported");
    }
}
```

TypeExtensions class has an extension method to get the default value of a Type (returned as an object).

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static object GetDefault(this Type t)
    {
        Func<object> f = GetDefault<object>; // quick hack to get generic method
        return f.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition().MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(null, null);
    }

    private static T GetDefault<T>()
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Then it's just a matter of chaining the calls together like `SqlDbType.Bit.ToType().GetDefault().ToString()`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var type = SqlDbType.Bit.ToType();
        Console.Write(SqlDbType.Bit.ToType().GetDefault().ToString());
    }
}
```